# Woocommerce Categories / Show subcategories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I`m trying to create categories and sub categories for my products . So far it look like this: [image]

-Furniture is a subcategory of Products . On furniture settings i choose  Display type to show Subcategories . Like the image : [image]

So my problem now is when i visit Furniture sub category , it shouldnt show all the subcategories of furniture in boxes ? All i get is this : [image]

I want when i visit -Furniture to show all its categories in boxes like the image above . Its only show the Living sub category .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the woocommerce settings . Go to

```
Woocommerce setting -> Products -> Display ->

Shop page display -> Select Show both

Default Category display -> Select Show both.
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that if you dont have any products into the subcategories it will not show them . So it seems that why i couldnt see any subcategories when i choose -Furniture and i could only see the Living subcategory .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try this into your function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty', 'show_empty_categories', 10, 1 );
function show_empty_categories ( $show_empty ) {
$show_empty  =  true;
// You can add other logic here too
return $show_empty;
}
```

also you could checkout following link for more in-depth understanding

[show-subcategories-link](http://blog.akhileshbc.com/display-empty-product-categories-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: Please vote up if its helps you. Thanks in advance for up .(y)